# How can I count the total amount of elements inside an each function?

Tags: jquery

Inside my each function I am pulling text from a div, adding it as a class to a parent element, and then I need to count how many elements have that class. The problem comes in because it's inside my each function as it counts up incrementally instead of just giving me the total amount.

You can see in my fiddle that the output is 1231211 and what I'm trying to get is 3211.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KqcWh/)

My HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">asdf</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">asdf</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">asdf</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">qwerty</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">qwerty</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">zxcv</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="nid">ghjk</div>
</div>

<div class="numbers">

</div>
```

My jQuery

```
$(".nid").each(function() {
    var nid = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().addClass(nid);
    var nidCount = $(".parent."+nid).length;
    $('.numbers').append(nidCount);
});
```

Comment: So you just need to count unique values or what? What is the original task you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I need to count unique values. So three parent elements will have the class of asdf. I need to count that and return the total, 3, instead of counting them incrementally, 123.

Comment: if you just need to count, why do you want to set it to the parent class? What is the original task?

Comment: Adding it as a class was part of my original plan, but I guess I don't really need to. I'm outputting info through views in Drupal, rewriting that output and adding the nid, then giving it a display none so I guess I could count those instead. Oops... hit enter...

Comment: "was part of my original plan" --- that's why you need to always explain the original task http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: So I need to count how many elements have that specific nid being displayed, well hidden, then output an image, or maybe html, based on that number.

Comment: Thanks for that link. This is my first post. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var counter = {};
$(".nid").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var count = counter[text] || 0;
    counter[text] = count + 1;
});
$.each(counter, function(key, value){
    $('.numbers').append(value);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MryDU/)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, the count is happening every time. So, you are counting all `asdf` for the first, 1, all `asdf` for the second, 2, etc. You could store the counts some other way in the loop, possibly with an object. Then, after the loop, print out the counts.

You could also aggregate the nids, add the classes to parent, then in a second loop, which is looping the aggregate nids, you could count how many parents have that particular class.

Comment: It sounds good, but I am definitely at a loss on how to execute that. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is appending `nidCount` to `.numbers` every time it counts a DIV. What you should do is something like this:

```
var numbers = {};
$(".nid").each(function() {
    var nid = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().addClass(nid);
    var nidCount = $(".parent."+nid).length;
    numbers[nid] = nidCount;
});

for (var key in numbers) {
    $('.numbers').append(numbers[key]);
}
```

Comment: 1. `numbers` should be an object not an array 2. you've missed `var` for `key`

Comment: @zerkms Corrected post, thanks! (It was working fine for me without those changes, probably my browser interpreting stuff liberally...)

Answer (score -1):

Try placing a comma between both the classes..

```
 var nidCount = $(".parent,."+nid).length;
```

Comment: That seems to count any elements with parent as a class. It is returning 7777777.